# Parsing Date Android EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy

Tags: java, android, datetime

Im triyng to format the following date:

```
 Wed Feb 12 18:30:06 GMT-03:00 2014
```

I tried the following code to parse it but im not achieving it.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
Date date = sdf.parse(status.getCreatedAt().toString());
```

Anyone know the correct format to parse this date?

Thanks!

Comment: What's `status.getCreatedAt()` exactly? You need to explain problem a little bit better. Give us more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your time zone is wrong. You need to use ZZZZ (note the capitalization). Your format string would then look like `"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ yyyy"` as noted on [the reference page](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: small z is for General time zone